# Python Numba @jit "Lowering Error"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, complex-numbers, numba

I have been making a program involving complex number calculations and three of the functions I am using are these:

```
import turtle
import cmath
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

@jit
def quadratics(arange=[0,10],brange=[0,100],crange=[0,100], step=2):
    l = []
    for a in range(arange[0],arange[1]+1,step):
        for b in range(brange[0],brange[1]+1,step):
            for c in range(crange[0],crange[1]+1,step):
                if a != 0:
                    l.append((-b+cmath.sqrt(b**2-4*a*c))/(2*a))
                    l.append((-b-cmath.sqrt(b**2-4*a*c))/(2*a))
    return l

def mindistance(point, roots):
    return min(np.array([(point.real-i.real)**2+(point.imag-i.imag)**2 for i in roots]))

@jit
def drawing_matrix(imsz=500,xrange=[-5,5],yrange=[-5,5],poly=2,acc=0.01):
    l = np.zeros((imsz, imsz))
    roots = quadratics()
    for x in range(0, imsz):
        for y in range(0, imsz):
            c = complex((x/imsz)*(xrange[1]-xrange[0])+xrange[0],(y/imsz)*(yrange[1]-yrange[0])+yrange[0])
            if mindistance(c, roots) <= acc:
                l[x,y] = 1
    return l
```

Now, I have been using Numba to speed things up with the `@jit` decorator and it's fine apart from `mindistance()`. If I put the `@jit` decorator on that function (which would be really useful, since it is called thousands of times during a program run) it produces the most almighty of error messages ending with:

```
numba.errors.LoweringError: Failed at object (object mode backend)
make_function(code=<code object <listcomp> at 0x000001F460FAB540, file "C:\Users\Isky\Documents\IT\Programs\Mathematics\AlgebraicNumbers.py", line 19>, name=$const0.7, defaults=None, closure=$0.5)
File "AlgebraicNumbers.py", line 19
[1] During: lowering "$0.8 = make_function(code=<code object <listcomp> at 0x000001F460FAB540, file "C:\Users\Isky\Documents\IT\Programs\Mathematics\AlgebraicNumbers.py", line 19>, name=$const0.7, defaults=None, closure=$0.5)" at C:\Users\Isky\Documents\IT\Programs\Mathematics\AlgebraicNumbers.py (19)
```

which is line 19 (as in `def mindistance()`). Can you tell me why Numba doesn't like this function?

Comment: try using `np.min` instead of the python built-in min

Comment: This works! Thank you!